# Remember the last selected item of a combobox

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog in a MFC project that contains a combobox with the following items: blue, black, yellow. When I start the dialog the combobox has the blue item selected. If I change to yellow, close the dialog and open the dialog again, I want the selected item to be yellow and not blue.

Any idee how can I remember the last selected item ?

Comment: Do you want to remember during 1 run of your whole program, or you want to remember even if the application was restarted?

Comment: No, if the application is restarted I don't care. Just when the specific dialog is closed and open, not the program

Comment: Yeah, well, isn't the dialog your own class? Can't you have a (possibly static) member that denotes last value?

Comment: But even if I have a static member in the dialog class, when I close the dialog I don't think the item will be saved. Maybe if the static member is in the main dialog of the program

Comment: When you close the dialog, static members won't disappear :)

Comment: Hmm, damm, you are right :) Please post it as an answer so i can vote & accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dialog class, have a static member and always set it to the last color used in the combo box. Since the member is static, it will persist even if you change the actual dialog object

Answer (score 3):

You can save it to registry.
Check the codeproject article: [History Combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/historycombo.aspx?msg=859855)

If you don't want to retain the selected item after the application is restarted, a `static` member will do.

Comment: This is applicable if you want to retain the selected item even after the application is closed.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the static member is just what I want it :)

Comment: I noticed your comment only after I posted the answer :)